# Navigation Drawer not opening when using android support library v23.4.0

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

Hello everyone I'm developing an app that uses old navigation drawer approach. When I update  `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` to  `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` my navigation drawer not opening.

I debugged code and look for deprecated items but could not find any error code or message. Everything works perfectly but navigation drawer is not opening. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, TapuInterface.IAuthorization {

    TapuUtils tapuUtils = new TapuUtils();
    String userMail, userPassword;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Tracker mTracker;
    Bundle bundle;
    String tapuAuth = "false";

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);

        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

        Countly.sharedInstance().init(this, getString(R.string.countly_server), getString(R.string.countly_key));

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert mActionBar != null;
        mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF297AA6));

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            userMail = bundle.getString("personname");
            userPassword = bundle.getString("personpassword");
            tapuAuth = bundle.getString("tapu");
        }

        TapuCredentials.setUserMail(userMail);
        TapuCredentials.setUserPassword(userPassword);
        TapuCredentials.setTapuAuth(tapuAuth);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainMapFragment.newInstance(position + 1), "MapFragment")
                .commit();
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.exit_alert))
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                        LoginActivity.fa.finish();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), null)
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mTracker.setScreenName(getResources().getString(R.string.main_screen));
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    }


}
```

**Here is my NavigationDrawer.class**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static NavigationDrawerAdapter myAdapter;
    public static ArrayList<ListItem> myItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public static UserCredentials mUserCredentials = new UserCredentials();
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private DynamicListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    static LegendFragment frLegend = new LegendFragment();
    Button mEditLayers, mShowLegend;
    String personName,userType,tapucontrol;
    TextView mLayersText;
    static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Bundle extras;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);



    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
            if(mUserCredentials.getUserName()==null || mUserCredentials.getPassword()==null){
                mUserCredentials.setUserAccount(extras.getString("username"), extras.getString("password"));
            }
            personName = extras.getString("personname");
            userType = extras.getString("usertype");
            tapucontrol = extras.getString("tapu");
        }


        mDrawerListView = (DynamicListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dynamiclistivew);
        mLayersText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_layers);
        myAdapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), myItems);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        mDrawerListView.setCheeseList(myItems);
        mDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        mEditLayers = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mShowLegend = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.legendbutton);
        mEditLayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (mEditLayers.getText().equals("Düzenle")) {
                    myAdapter.setEditMode(true);
                    mEditLayers.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.ok));


                } else {
                    myAdapter.setEditMode(false);
                    mEditLayers.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.editlayers));


                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;

    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                null,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);


            }
        };


        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (frLegend.isAdded()) {
            ft.remove(frLegend);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            mEditLayers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLayersText.setText("Katmanlar");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           // showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                Intent s = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchMainActivity.class);
                s.putExtra("username", mUserCredentials.getUserName());
                s.putExtra("password", mUserCredentials.getPassword());
                s.putExtra("tapu",tapucontrol);
                startActivity(s);
                break;
            case R.id.action_basemaps:
                Intent cb = new Intent(getActivity(), BaseMapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(cb);
                break;
            case R.id.action_addlayer:
                if (isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                    Intent al = new Intent(getActivity(), AddLayerActivity.class);
                    al.putExtra("usertype", userType);
                    startActivity(al);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_about:
                Intent au = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
                au.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(au);
                break;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }

    public class ListItem {
        String textdata;
        Integer progress;

        public ListItem(String textdata, int progress) {
            this.textdata = textdata;
            this.progress = progress;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            ListItem ndListItemObject = (ListItem) o;
            return this.textdata.equalsIgnoreCase(ndListItemObject.textdata);
        }

    }


    public void addLayersection(String name, int progress) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(name, progress);

        if (myItems.size() == 0) {
            myItems.add(0, listItem);

        } else {
            if (myItems.size() == 0) {
                myItems.add(0, listItem);
            } else {

                if (myItems.contains(listItem)) {
                    myItems.remove(listItem);
                } else {
                    myItems.add(0, listItem);


                }
            }
        }

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public int getListSizee() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Drawer is locked.

Change

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

to

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the late solution that I find with myself. drawerOpenCloseControl is boolean flag. I am controlling true or false. And then open and close manually.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:
            if(drawerOpenCloseControl){
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
                drawerOpenCloseControl = false;
            }
            else{
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                drawerOpenCloseControl = true;
            }
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```